# How does inplace add work in tuples if tuples do not include __iadd__ but still use INPLACE_ADD instruction?

Tags: python, list, tuples, in-place

We know `tuple`s do  not support item assignment, but we can perform `inplace add` with tuples, however, this *creates a new object*, as tuples are immutable. for example:

```
>>> t1 = (1, 2)
>>> id(t1)
154311048
>>> t1 += (3, 4)
>>> t1
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> id(t1)
157955320
```

That's all good. On the other hand, `list`s are mutable and do not create new objects while performing inplace add.

Now I was under the impression that inplace add in python was implemented with `__iadd__` magic, so:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l1 += [4, 5]
# is same as
>>> l1 = l1.__iadd__([4,5])   # 1
# but, again for lists, this is also same as, simply
>>> l1.__iadd__([4,5])        # 2
```

I surmise that, as inplace operation is not guaranteed for immutable objects, python assigns `l1.__iadd__([4,5])` to `l1`, otherwise, for lists, simply calling `l1.__iadd__([4,5])` without assigning it back to `l1` would modify `l1` inplace.

So, with that in mind, I guessed tuples might work like this, i.e.,

```
>>> t1 = t1.__iadd__((3,4))
```

But,

> `Traceback (most recent call last):`
>
> `File "<ipython-input-12-e8ed2ace9f7f>", line 1, in <module>`
>      `t1.__iadd__((1,2))`
>
> `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '__iadd__'`

Indeed, `'__iadd__' in dir(tuple)` evaluates to `False`. Then I thought, may be internally, Python makes a list out of tuples, performs the `__iadd__` and converts the result back into `tuple` (I don't know why would anyone do that! Moreover, that wouldn't explain the performance benefits of tuples over list) or for immutable objects, `__iadd__` might just fallback to `__add__` and return the value, but after doing `dis`:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis('t1 += (3, 4)')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (t1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 ((3, 4))
              4 INPLACE_ADD
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (t1)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

But the bytecode has the instruction `INPLACE_ADD`!
For list it goes like:

```
>>> dis('l1 += [1,2]')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (l1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BUILD_LIST               2
              8 INPLACE_ADD
             10 STORE_NAME               0 (l1)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Furthermore, in case of `list` there is an extra instruction `BUILD_LIST`, so `tuples` do not build a list either!

As you can see, this is extremely confusing for me. Could someone explain what's going on, how does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INPLACE_ADD` falls back to regular addition with `__add__` and `__radd__` if `__iadd__` doesn't exist or returns `NotImplemented`.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also explain why there's a need for `BUILD_LIST` while inplace adding in `list`? If not I can ask a separate question if you want.

Comment: @SayandipDutta It is building the `[1,2]` list to pass as the second argument to `INPLACE_ADD`.

Comment: Yes, but why can't it do something equivalent to this `2 LOAD_CONST               0 ((3, 4))`, I mean like: `2 LOAD_CONST               0 ([3, 4])`?

Comment: @SayandipDutta it's because `list` defines `__iadd__`, so the internal compiler builds the bytecode to work with the method on `list`, unlike `tuple`, where the compiler just falls back to `t = t + (3,4)`. I personally find this fallback to be a flaw with the implementation just for the sake of convenience (an initially unintended oversight or other).